# How can I split a RxJS-Stream into multiple indepent streams

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have the following usecase. When I open my angular component in my ngOnInit I'm subscribing to the observable from the route-resolver (this.activatedRoute.data). Once this emits data I wan't to start multiple http-requests which should run and complete independently from each other. Since nesting subscribes is an anti-pattern I thought about using switchMap in combination with forkJoin. This works fine so far except that it only finishes once all http-request are completed. But since those requests are 100% independent I would prefer to update my ui everytime one of the requests completes. How can I do this without nesting subscribes?

That is my current implementation.

```
this.activatedRoute.data.pipe(
    switchMap(data => {
      return forkJoin(
        httpRequest1(data),
        httpRequest2(data),
        )
    })
).subscribe((res)=>{
    this.list1 = res[0];
    this.list2 = res[1];
})
```

Comment: please include your current code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use [Merge](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/merge) (Flattens multiple Observables together by blending their values into one Observable) as below:

```js
this.activatedRoute.data
  .pipe(
    switchMap(data => {
      return merge(
        httpRequest1(data).pipe(tap(x => updateUI1(x))),
        httpRequest2(data).pipe(tap(x => updateUI2(x))),
      )
    })
  )
```

Comment: Your solution switches to the httpRequest after a single emit. The requirement is after completion.

Comment: `@Jonathan Stellwag`  `activatedRoute.data`  never completes

Comment: I was just reading his question: "Once this completes I wan't to start multiple http-requests which should run and complete independently from each other."

Comment: I really meant the http requests should fire when the this.activatedRoute.data emits data. Actually this answer could work for my use. Didn't think about updating the my ui in a tap(). In my case I would switch the merge for a forkJoin so I can toggle my loader in the subscribe when all requests are completed.

Answer (score 0):

**FYI: This answer works only if you rely on this.activatedRoute.data to complete**

You could use the [concat](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/concat) operator

```
concat(this.activatedRoute.data, httpRequest1)
concat(this.activatedRoute.data, httpRequest2)
```

The given observables switch to the next after the previous given is completed.

Does this fit your requirements? You are a bit unspecific what "and complete independently from each other" means.

Comment: Not exactly as I would like to run the requests in parallel.

Comment: Then update your question: "Once this completes I wan't to start multiple http-requests which should run and complete independently from each other."